# Unable to insert the records in the tables in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my store procedure, when I am executing it for testing , it says records inserted successfully, but I cannot see any records in the table.   Data is inserted into 3 tables- Shipment , Ship_commodity and Commodity_Hazmat. These 3 tables are inter connected.
id from shipment table=shipment id from Ship_commodity
id from Ship_commodity table=commodity id of Commodity_Hazmat table

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_InsertBulk]
(       
@ShipmentType       VARCHAR(10),
@SCACCode           VARCHAR(4),
@SCNumber           VARCHAR(12),
@CountryLoading     VARCHAR(2),
@PortLoading        VARCHAR(21),    
@ShipperName        VARCHAR(60),    
@ShipperAddress     VARCHAR(100),
@ShipperCity        VARCHAR(50),
@ShipmentCountry    VARCHAR(2),
@ShipmentProvince       VARCHAR(3),
@ShipperZip         VARCHAR(15),
@ShipperPhone       VARCHAR(20),
@ShipperEmail       VARCHAR(100),

@ConsigneeName      VARCHAR(60),    
@ConsigneeAddress   VARCHAR(100),
@ConsigneeCity      VARCHAR(50),    
@ConsigneeCountry   VARCHAR(2),
@ConsigneeState VARCHAR(3), 
@ConsigneeZip       VARCHAR(15),
@ConsigneePhone     VARCHAR(20),
@ConsigneeEmail     VARCHAR(100),

@Description        VARCHAR(90),
@Quantity           INT,
@QuantityUnit       VARCHAR(3), 
@Weight             INT,
@WeightUnitCode     VARCHAR(1),
@Countrycode        VARCHAR(2),
@Value              VARCHAR(8),
@HarmonizedCode     VARCHAR(30),
@MarksNumbers       VARCHAR(48),
@CmdHMCode1         VARCHAR(10),
@CmdHMName1         VARCHAR(24),    
@CmdHMPhone1        VARCHAR(256),
@CmdHMCode2         VARCHAR(10),
@CmdHMName2         VARCHAR(24),
@CmdHMPhone2        VARCHAR(256),
@CmdHMCode3         VARCHAR(10),
@CmdHMName3         VARCHAR(24),
@CmdHMPhone3        VARCHAR(256),
@CustomControl      VARCHAR(50),
@DateShipmentLeft   VARCHAR(50),
@InbondEntryType    VARCHAR(2),
@InbondDestination  VARCHAR(5),
@OnwardCarrier      VARCHAR(4),
@BondedCarrier      VARCHAR(12),
@Inbond             VARCHAR(9),
@TransferCarrier    VARCHAR(12),
@ForeignPortDestination VARCHAR(12),
@EstimatedDeparture VARCHAR(8),
@MexiPediNumber     VARCHAR(12),
@RetVal             VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT

)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @CMDId BIGINT
DECLARE  @Id                    BIGINT
DECLARE @ShipmentID         BIGINT
BEGIN TRY   
BEGIN TRAN;

BEGIN
INSERT INTO 
dbo.Shipment 
(ShipmentType, scaccode, ShipmentControl, countryLoading, PortLoading, ShipperName, 
 ShipperAddressOne, 
 ShipperCity, ShipperCountry, ShipperProvince, ShipperZip, ShipperPhone, ShipperEmail, ConsigneeName, 
 ConsigneeAddressOne, ConsigneeCity, ConsigneeCountry, ConsigneeState, ConsigneeZip,
 ConsigneePhone, ConsigneeEmail, ResponseCode, astrayExportDate, bondType, bondDestPort, 
 bondOnwardscac, bondCarrierIRS, bondNumber, bondTransferIRS, bondForeignPort, bondDepartureDate, 
 MexiPediNumber)
VALUES  
(@ShipmentType, @SCACCode, @SCNumber, @CountryLoading, @PortLoading, @ShipperName, @ShipperAddress, 
@ShipperCity, @ShipmentCountry, @ShipmentProvince,                  @ShipperZip, @ShipperPhone, 
@ShipperEmail, @ConsigneeName, @ConsigneeAddress, @ConsigneeCity, @ConsigneeCountry, @ConsigneeState, 
@ConsigneeZip,@ConsigneePhone, @ConsigneeEmail, @CustomControl, @DateShipmentLeft, @InbondEntryType, 
@InbondDestination, @OnwardCarrier, @BondedCarrier, @Inbond, @TransferCarrier, 
@ForeignPortDestination, @EstimatedDeparture, @MexiPediNumber)
SELECT @Id=@@IDENTITY
    SET @RetVal = 'true|Record Inserted Successfully|'+CAST(@Id AS VARCHAR)
END                                                 


 BEGIN  
 SELECT @ShipmentID=@Id
 INSERT INTO dbo.Ship_commodity(ShipmentID,[Description],Quantity,manifestUnitCode, 
 [weight],weightUnitCode,countryCode,customsShipmentValue,commodityCode,MarksNumbers)                         
 VALUES    
 (@ShipmentID, @Description, @Quantity, @QuantityUnit, @Weight, @WeightUnitCode, @Countrycode, 
 @Value,@HarmonizedCode,@MarksNumbers)
 SELECT @CMDId=@@IDENTITY       
                                        
    SET @RetVal = 'true|Record Inserted Successfully|'+CAST(@CMDId AS VARCHAR)
END

BEGIN

IF(ISNULL(@CmdHMCode1,'')<>'')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Commodity_Hazmat(CommodityID,HazmatCode,HazmatContact,HazmatComNum) 
                              VALUES(@CMDId,@CmdHMCode1,@CmdHMName1,@CmdHMPhone1)
IF(ISNULL(@CmdHMCode2,'')<>'')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Commodity_Hazmat(CommodityID,HazmatCode,HazmatContact,HazmatComNum) 
                              VALUES(@CMDId,@CmdHMCode2,@CmdHMName2,@CmdHMPhone2)
IF(ISNULL(@CmdHMCode3,'')<>'')
    INSERT INTO dbo.Commodity_Hazmat(CommodityID,HazmatCode,HazmatContact,HazmatComNum) 
                              VALUES(@CMDId,@CmdHMCode3,@CmdHMName3,@CmdHMPhone3)       
     END                       
COMMIT TRAN;                                            
END TRY                                                 
BEGIN CATCH                                         
    ROLLBACK TRAN;                              
    SET @RetVal='false|Technical Error-'+ERROR_MESSAGE()+'|'+ ERROR_PROCEDURE() + ' LineNo : ' + 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, ERROR_LINE()) +'|'
END CATCH                                       
END
GO
```

[image: image for executing the sp]

Comment: Presumably one of your `if` statements is generating an exception.

Comment: `@@IDENTITY` is not safe in the face of triggers. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead

Comment: I didn't say it will solve your problem, it is a side issue. Are all the tables empty? Because those 3 last `if` statements will bail out on the input you have given. Start by removing the try/catch and see if it gives an error.

Comment: You might check the Messages screen. You should see the "row(s) affected" message for each INSERT. "(0 row(s) affected)" would not be what you expect.  (Based on that I do not see SET NOCOUNT ON in the procedure).  Or , you can explicitly check by PRINTs after each INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

You have a long transaction block that can fail in many different places. I might suggest that you put some auditing directly in the stored procedure.

In particular, you can add a `print` statement to the `catch` block to see if there are any other errors that are arising.

I would add a new variable, something like:

```
declare @auditLevel int = 0;
```

Then conditionally print to see where there is a problem:

```
if @auditLevel > 0
begin
    print 'Hey, I''m here';
end;
```

Comment: I tried inserting into 1 table , then also its not inserting into the table :-

Comment: i tried this , @auditLevel  but it is not going into the catch block

Comment: tried SCOPE_IDENTITY() as well, still the same issue

Comment: i tried , i am able to insert into shipment and ship_commodity, but in the third table insertion is not happening , may be if statements causig an issue

Comment: How to insert into table with same id but different value in another column in sql? this is what i am doing in third table -Commodity_Hazmat . How can we write this. because mine is not working.